# How to create plugin installer for adobe after effects

Tags: adobe, after-effects

Does anyone know how to create an installer for Adobe After Effects plugins, which installs a plugin, directly in the Adobe After Effects plugin folder on the user machine.

Comment: Your question is weird. Do you mean "How to create a software that install After Effects plugins in the proper place" ?

Comment: You are looking for a `C++` or a `python` solution ?

Comment: Both are acceptable can you give me some sort of guild or link where to start from.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options here, but first: the best place to put plugins is in the Common/MediaCore/ folder, since it will be installed for all AE (and Premiere) versions. This way, you don't have to release a new installer because a new AE version (with a new name) came out. Read more here: https://ae-plugins.docsforadobe.dev/intro/where-installers-should-put-plug-ins.html#intro-where-installers-should-put-plug-ins

Plugins installation is very easy in a sense: It's just a copy of the .plugin or .aex file in the right folder.

I would argue that the AE user community is used to installing files by copy-pasting them in the right location because of the extensive use of Scripts and Plugins in AE. The classic way of distributing your plugin is a PDF or a readme file that tells the user where to put your plugin file.

But if you want to build an installer, (maybe because you have more files and dlls to install), there are a few options, but I had success in the past with [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). You also have to consider that AE is cross-platform (Mac and Windows), so your installer should also be available in both platforms.